# unattended bash script (*.sh) with password

Tags: bash, scripts, ssh

I want automatically made full image backup from any servers.
Manually it works like:

```
ssh username@Server.xxx "nohup sudo -S dd if=/dev/sda | gzip -1 -" | dd of=fullServerXX-`date +%d%m%y`.img.gz
```

and needed two times a password - for ssh and sudo. I want to do that by cron.
How can i put this into a bash script, give the password and let run that unattended?

Comment: eh the middle command you add to /etc/crontab of the server itself. Negates the use of sudo as you can add user `root` to the line. No need to use ssh. If you want it copied to anther machine: rsync it. You can do that too using /etc/crontab and have it automated. crontab edited after `sudo -i` and `/etc/crontab` do not need sudo. Both use or can use `root`. That `dd` is going to take some time so best to NOT use ssh but do it directly on that server.

Comment: i wont sync files, i want to have a disk image and i need it zipped.

Comment: You likely do not get what I stated.  I would create the disk image on the server, zip it on the server and rsync the file. Less complex, less depending on the connection to the server and rsync can continue where is stopped if the connection is interupted.